# How to populate DataGridView in static method?

Tags: c#, datagridview, static, static-methods

I am trying to fill `DataGridView`. However, since I am doing it on `FileSystemWatcher` handler, which is **static class**, it gives me error:

```
An object reference is required for non-static field, method, or property
```

If I change class to **non-static** then `EventHandler` gives same error. I am currently in loop and couldnt find solution. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

```
    class FCheck
    {
        public static void tpCard_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadId:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + "File:" + e.FullPath);

            if (Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath) == ".f")
            {
// Do something....

                Form1.populateTable(tp);
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is Main Form1:

```
        public void checkTPFiles()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"F:\tmp");
            fw.Created += LSCheck.tpCard_Created;
            fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;                                         
        }

        public static void populateTable(TpCard tpCard)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
            row.Cells[1].Value = tpCard.FNumber;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form class to write to controls on the form.  You have only one form, but looking at my two form project may help.  You class FCheck is equivalent to a 2nd form.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng could you please help me more? I mean could you write snippet for better understanding?

Comment: I recommending a solution like rboe.  But I need to see you project structure to give good answer.  I don't know from your posted code the relationship between you classes.  I don't know if you have a form project or a console project and the instances of the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to pass a `Form1` instance to your `FCheck` class.

In your **Form1**:

```
    public void checkTPFiles()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"F:\tmp");

        var fCheck = new FCheck(this);       // <= passes Form1 instance
        fw.Created += fCheck.tpCard_Created; // <= no static call anymore
        fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public void populateTable(TpCard tpCard)
    {

    }
```

In your class **FCheck**:

```
class FCheck
{
    private readonly Form1 _form;

    public FCheck(Form1 form) 
    {
        _form = form;  // <= remember Form1 instance for future use
    }

    public void tpCard_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadId:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + "File:" + e.FullPath);

        if (Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath) == ".f")
        {                
            // Do something....

            _form.populateTable(tp);  // <= now it is possible to call instance methods
        }

    }
}
```

This is not the finest solution of all, because the classes are *tightly coupled*.

Using events and delegates so that `FCheck` raises an event and `Form1` is reacting to it, would be a better approach. The above solution is meant to be a first step to get you running.

Comment: this solution solved staitc issue. However I am getting exception about thread issue. It says `Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`